# Iterate through files in rails directory, do something with filename?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my rails project structure I have created a folder pages under the path db/pages . I would like to iterate through all the html.erb files in this db/pages directory and **DoSomething** with the filename of each of these files. All this should happen when I run rake db:seed so I have placed my code in seeds.rb

Below is my attempted code:

```
source_path = "/db/pages"

Dir.glob("#{source_path}/*.html.erb").each do |html_page|
  DoSomething html_page
end
```

This seems to be doing nothing when I run rake db:seed. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try prepending Rails.root:

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}#{source_path}/*.html.erb").each do |html_page|
```

An even more correct approach would be:

```
source_path = Rails.root.join('db', 'pages')

Dir.glob("#{source_path}/*.html.erb").each do |html_page|
```

Comment: This works but gives the whole path to the filename...how do I just extract the filename only from the path? So I want example from C:/Sites/MyApp/db/pages/example.html.erb

Comment: You can use `File.basename` for this: `DoSomething File.basename(html_page, ".html.erb")`